# How to serialize (to comma separated list) SQL rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a view with columns along the lines of:

`ID, Name`

I want to add a third column `Properties` which must contain a comma separated list of properties. I can get the properties from a joining table, but at the moment joining will return a separate row for each property. What's the best way of pulling a single row for a comma separated list?

In the past I think i've used a user defined function with a cursor. It'd be great if I can do this without the UDF but i'm not 100% sure. If not, i'm sure I can get rid of the cursor with a more intelligence UDF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, Name, Properties = STUFF((
    SELECT N',' + PropertyName FROM dbo.Properties
    WHERE ID = x.ID
    FOR XML PATH(''), 
    TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, N'')
FROM dbo.ViewName AS x
GROUP BY ID, Name;
```